# How to specify loadBalancerIP for a Service in GKE without actually typing in a static IP into yaml?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've configured a static IP `my-static-ip` in Google Cloud and created a K8s Service that looks similar to this:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myAppService
spec:
  selector:
    app: myApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
```

Is there a way to reference that IP by name `my-static-ip` to keep the yaml clean?

I need static IP because it's the only way in GCP to have a load balancer for both TCP and UDP (you have to actually create two and set them to a static IP).

I've looked at Ingress that understands static IP labels, but it's HTTP(S) only.